# How to write SQL query to calculate instances where a row containing a distinct id occurs 7 days after the fist occurrence if the unique id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to return a date, the count of `unique_id`s first occurrences on that date, the number `unique_id`s that occurred 7 days after their first occurrence and the percentage of occurrences after 7 days / number of first occurrences.

example `data_import` table

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|         time        |   distinct_id    |  
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/01     |        1         |   first instance of `1`
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/01     |        2         |   also first instance, but does not occur 7 days later
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/02     |        1         |   should be disregarded (not first instance of 1)
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/02     |        3         |   first instance of `3`
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/08     |        1         |   First instance 7 days after first instance of `1`
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/08     |        1         |   Don't count as this is the 2nd instance of `1` on this day 
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/09     |        3         |   7 days after first instance of `3`
+---------------------+------------------+
|      2018/10/09     |        1         |   7 days after non-first instance of `1`
+---------------------+------------------+
```

And the expected return.

```
+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
|       time          | num_of_1st_instance  | num_occur_7_days_after | percent_used_7_days_after |  
+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
|     2018/10/01      |         2            |          1             |           .50             |  
+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
|     2018/10/02      |         1            |          1             |            1.0            |  
+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
|     2018/10/03      |         0            |          0             |             0             |  
+---------------------+----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
```

The query I have written is close, but counts occurrences other that the first for a `distinct_id`.

In my example, this query would include the occurrence of `distinct_id` `1` on `2018/10/02` and it's occurrence seven days after `2018/10/02` on `2018/10/09`. Not wanted as the `2018/10/02` occurrence of `distinct_id` `1` is not it's first.

```sql
SELECT
  data_import.time AS date,
  count(distinct data_import.distinct_id) AS num_installs_on_install_date,
  count(distinct future_activity.distinct_id) AS num_occur_7_days_after,
  count(distinct future_activity.distinct_id) / count(distinct data_import.distinct_id)::float AS percent_used_7_days_after
FROM data_import
LEFT JOIN data_import AS future_activity ON
  data_import.distinct_id = future_activity.distinct_id
    AND
  DATE(data_import.time) = DATE(future_activity.time) - INTERVAL '7 days'
    AND
  data_import.time = ( SELECT
                             time
                           FROM
                             data_import
                           WHERE
                             distinct_id = future_activity.distinct_id
                           ORDER BY
                             time
                           limit
                             1 )
GROUP BY DATE(data_import.time)
```

I hope that I explained this clearly. Please let me know how I can change my current query or a different approach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Does this do what you want?

```
select di.time, sum( (seqnum = 1)::int) as first_instance,
       sum( flag_7day ) as num_after_7_day,
       sum( (seqnum = 1)::int) * 1.0 / sum( flag_7day ) as ratio
from (select di.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by distinct_id order by time) as seqnum,
             (case when exists (select 1 from data_import di2 where di2.distinct_id = di.distinct_id and di2.time > di.time + interval '7 day')
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as flag_7day
      from data_import di
     ) di
group by di.time;
```

This doesn't return days with no first instances.  Those days seem a bit awkward with respect to the ratio, so I'm not 100% sure that you really need them.  If you do, it is easy enough to include a `generate_series()` to generate all dates in the range that you want.